# Force macro definition before #if directive

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation, iar

I was surprised to learn that undefined macros are automatically assigned with the value of 0 when used in a preprocessor expression. For example:

```
//#define A
#if A == 0
// do something
#endif
```

This code will compile in the "do something" part, while I expected it to give an error. I found out that GCC has an [option to warn against this case](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_4.html):

> - Identifiers that are not macros, which are all considered to be the number zero. This allows you to write `#if MACRO` instead of `#ifdef MACRO`, if you know that `MACRO`, when defined, will always have a nonzero value. Function-like macros used without their function call parentheses are also treated as zero.
>
>   In some contexts this shortcut is undesirable. The `-Wundef` option causes GCC to warn whenever it encounters an identifier which is not a macro in an `#if`.

So, I am looking for the equivalent option to `-Wundef` for the **IAR Embedded Workbench IDE**. Is there such an option?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a construct like `#if defined(A) && A == 0` ?

Comment: You could adopt a coding standard that defining a preprocessor token to `0` should have the same semantics as it not being defined at all (within other preprocessor tests, that is); rendering this issue moot.

Comment: @WilliamMcBrine - There is no reason why not to use this except it makes the code look more convoluted and requires a 2nd read by a 3rd party to understand the intention behind that line (that appears many times across the big project). Especially, when GCC provides such an elegant solution.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - This is basically what I ended up with, but yet, it relies on some preliminary assumptions, and requires that all developers in the project follow the rule. For example, I replaced all the relevant `#ifndef A` directives by `#if A != 1`. GCC's option is much more robust and elegant.

Comment: Where are the macro definitions coming from? From commandline flags e.g. `-DA=0 -DB=1`?

Comment: No. Mostly from a file concentrating global definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IAR C/C++ compiler in IAR Embedded Workbench can detect this. However, by default it's configured as a *remark*, which isn't shown.

You can either use the command line option `--remarks`, or raise the severity if it to a warning or error using `--diag_warning=Pe193`or `--diag_error=Pe193`.

Comment: Thanks! I could not find a list of diagnostics messages in the documentation (so we know what other valuable important remarks can be escalated). Is there any?

Comment: There are far too many diagnostics messages to list them in a manual. However, you can use the command line option `--diagnostics_tables` to list them.

Answer (score 1):

You say `cpp -WUndef` check is impractical at build time. Assuming your code is under SCM control, there's also commit time to the earliest quality-controlled repo. You could add a commit-hook for this check or extend an existing one.

If this would be an innovation for you, consider what other code-quality
checks it would be nice to automate this way.

Comment: I am unaware of SVN hooks for doing such things. Will investigate that.